# How to reset Plotly heatmap Level if the level broke by price?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to to create a heatmap with candle stick chart together , in heatmap i would like to reset the heatmap level when the levels is closed by price,

```
def generate_heatmap(data, price_levels, date_range):
    L100x = calculate_price_levels(data)
    heatmap = np.zeros((len(price_levels) - 1, len(date_range)))

    close_gt_open = data['Close'] > data['Open']
    open_gt_close = data['Open'] > data['Close']

    for j in range(len(price_levels) - 1):
        price_level = price_levels[j]
        next_price_level = price_levels[j + 1]

        cell_value = np.zeros(len(date_range), dtype=int)
        for i, date in enumerate(date_range):
            date_mask = (data.index <= date)

            if date_mask.any() and np.any((data[date_mask]['Low'] < price_level)):
                cell_value[i] = 0
            else:
                cell_value[i] += np.sum(
                    [
                        (date_mask & (L100x >= price_level) & (L100x < next_price_level) & close_gt_open),
                       
                    ]
                )

        heatmap[j, :] = cell_value

    return heatmap, date_range, price_levels[:-1]
```

here is the code

in code above when price close below level i did set cell value to zero , it works but later the broken level  never gets colored again even if condition is true for it ,
the question is how to reset it when broke but it should be allowed to be colored again starting from first occurrence .

thanks